# how to solve misused promise function

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

found this piece of code which is actually working but eslint is complaining about the misused promise

```
this.subject$.pipe(delay(this.debounceTime || 0)).subscribe(async ({ entry, observer }) => {
            const target = entry.target as HTMLElement;
            const isStillVisible = await this.isVisible(target);

            isStillVisible ? this.visible.emit() : this.invisible.emit();
        });
```

`ESLint: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected.(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)`

i need to refactor this function to get rid of the eslint error

tried asynchronous IIFE inside the callback

Comment: "tried asynchronous IIFE inside the callback" can you post the code for this attempt as well ?

Comment: You can either a) make the callback not async and use `.then` instead of await on the `isVisible` call or b) put in a directive for ESLint to ignore that error. That's honestly a flaw in the typings for rxjs, the type of the argument function to subscribe should really be `void | Promise<void>`, but you work with whatcha got.

Comment: You can a) just ignore the warning, there's no problem here or b) refactor to `.then()` or an IIFE or c) actually use rxjs combinators instead of `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert promises via `from` but as @Eddi commented (thanks!) this isn't required for `switchMap` since this converts to an observable under the hood

```
this.subject$.pipe(
  delay(this.debounceTime || 0),
  switchMap(({ entry, observer }) => {
    const target = entry.target as HTMLElement;
    return this.isVisible(target)
  })
).subscribe((isStillVisible) => {
  isStillVisible ? this.visible.emit() : this.invisible.emit();
});
```

I don't think the order of the switchMap and delay matters but I'd check this.

Comment: No need to use `from()` here. `switchMap` also accepts Promises.

Answer (score 0):

An `async` function implicitly returns a promise. You can change your callback to the following and it should still behave the same way but get rid of the error you are getting.

```js
this.subject$.pipe(delay(this.debounceTime || 0)).subscribe(({ entry, observer }) => {
    const target = entry.target as HTMLElement;
    this.isVisible(target)
    .then(function(isStillVisible) {
        isStillVisible ? this.visible.emit() : this.invisible.emit();
    });
});
```

This way the callback you pass to subscribe no longer returns a promise.